# How to reload context in Spring.Net

Tags: .net, spring.net

I would simply like to know the answer:

```
using Spring.Context.Support;
...

var context = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
var myObject = (MyObject)context.GetObject("MyObject");

// Making changes to the config file...

???

// Is there a way to reload context 
// so I can have my newly updated object
// without restarting the whole application?

var myObjectWithChanges = (MyObject)context.GetObject("MyObject");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
context.Refresh();
```

This reloads all object definitions from their persistent representation (e.g. xml configuration).

The refresh method is not part of the `IApplicationContext` interface, which is the inferred type of the `context` variable in your snippet. However. it is part of `AbstractApplicationContext`, from which most Spring.net application contexts derive.